How do I use Start- Job to start a function with parameters stored in another ps1?
the ps1 containing the function:
function MyFunction ($path) {
#does something
}

the ps1 calling the function:
Import-Module .\FunctionParent.ps1
$job = Start-Job -ArgumentList $PSScriptRoot -FilePath "MyFunction .ps1"

$dll = $PSScriptRoot+'\Interop.CCProjectMgrLib.dll'
Write-Host $dll -foreground Yellow

Start-Sleep 5

$JobStatus = $job.State
Write-Host $job.State -foreground Yellow

noob question I know but how do I call the start-job command properly?

Can you expand on what you mean by "properly"? What's the problem with the current code?

well the function is supposed to close a program using c# code. Running the function by itself works but when calling the above code
$job = Start-Job -ArgumentList $PSScriptRoot -FilePath "MyFunction .ps1"
then it displays no error but neither does it work.

I assume that one of the errors is that I do not specify which function to call

Pass a scriptblock to Start-Job, then make sure to dot-source the script before calling the function:
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  param($RootPath)

  # dot-source script
  . (Join-Path $RootPath -ChildPath MyFunction.ps1)

  # invoke function
  MyFunction -Path $RootPath
} -ArgumentList $PSScriptRoot


It worked like magic. Ty very much
